# WCF Contract namespace not being recognized

Tags: c#, wcf, datacontractserializer, datacontract

I am running into an issue when I am trying to specify a custom namespace for my contract objects for my WCF services.

I have the following two contracts:

```
[MessageContract(WrapperNamespace="http://www.mysite.com/Contracts/Users")]
public class CreateUserRequest
{
    [MessageBodyMember]
    public User User { get; set; }
}
[MessageContract(WrapperNamespace="http://www.mysite.com/Contracts/Users")]
public class CreateUserRequest
{
    [MessageBodyMember]
    public int ID {get;set;

    [MessageBodyMember]
    public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

The  definiton for this operation using this contract is the following:

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(BodyStyle=WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
    CreateUserResponse CreateUser(CreateUserRequest request);
```

I am sending the following XML with content-type **application/xml** to this service operation.

```
<CreateUserRequest xmlns="http://www.mysite.com/Contracts/Users">
        <User> 
               <First>John</First>
               <Last>Smith</Last>
               <Username>john</Username>
               <Password>password</Password>
        </User>
</CreateUserRequest>
```

I have also tried specifying the namespace again in the opening User tag, but when I debug my operation User is coming in as null.

I tried to do a Test() method that returned this object, and it seems to not be recognizing the namespace changes, or it is just not working. Any ideas why?

Comment: what exactly do you mean by 'not be recognizing the namespace changes, or it is just not wor'? Can you post error messages?

Comment: "...when I debug my operation, User is coming in as null"